# What does "critical rendering path" mean?

Tags: optimization, rendering

I'm looking for a concise explanation of what is meant by the "critical rendering path", specifically as to how it relates to web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The critical rendering path is the series of events that occur to
>   render the things required for just the initial view of that webpage
>   (above the fold content).

https://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/critical-render-path.html